# How can I keep the new files and delete the files older than 7200 seconds only?

Tags: php, unlink

How can I keep the new files (Less than 7200 seconds) and delete the older files only?

## My php code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam"); // bepaal de tijd zone!
// Bepaal het root path
$site_root_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';

// Leegt de cache map en verwijderd de bestanden op basis van de leeftijd
function verwijder_cache(){
    global $site_root_path;
    $site_cache = ($site_root_path . 'cache');
    
    // tijd in seconden dat de bestanden toegestaan zijn in de cache directory te verblijven
    $seconds_oud = 7200; // 604800 is 7 dagen, 7200 is 2 uur!
    
    // directory check-in first
    if (is_dir($site_cache)){
        $verwerk = opendir($site_cache);
        while (false !== ($tmp_site_cache_files = readdir($verwerk))){
            // We gaan nu alles verwijderen behalve index.php, .htaccess en alle sub mappen in de cache directory
            if ($tmp_site_cache_files != "." && $tmp_site_cache_files != ".." && $tmp_site_cache_files != "index.php" && $tmp_site_cache_files != ".htaccess"){
                $verschil = (time() - filectime($site_cache / $tmp_site_cache_files));
                if ($verschil >= $seconds_oud){ // Testje...
                    unlink($site_cache. '/' . $tmp_site_cache_files);
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    closedir($verwerk);
                    echo 'Alle bestanden, ouder dan ' . $seconds_oud . ' seconden zijn verwijderd van de server website cache!' . "\r\n";
                    }
                    // Dit zou nooit mogen gebeuren...
                    else
                        {
                        trigger_error('CACHE DIRECTORY ERROR');
                        }
                        }
                        verwijder_cache();
                        ?>
```

I'd like to delete files from a folder with php7.
I use the code displayed above and I'd like to keep files younger than 7200 seconds only, files over 7200 seconds should be deleted from the folder.

I also want to keep index.php, .htaccess and all directories/folders in the cache folder

The code does delete the files corectly and doesn't delete the files I'd like to keep but it does delete the files less than 7200 seconds as well.

How can I keep the new files (Less than 7200 seconds) and delete the older files only?

Comment: Looks like `verschil = (time() - filectime($site_cache / $tmp_site_cache_files));` is wrong.  Should be `verschil = (time() - filectime($site_cache . '/' . $tmp_site_cache_files));`

Comment: @drew010 Your comment did the trick, thank you for the pointing it out, I replaced the `/` with ` . '/'. ` : `$verschil = (time() - filectime($site_cache . '/' . $tmp_site_cache_files));` and the script is fully working, Thanks again!